How to get user id in page route with NextJS
I have done the tutorial of creating a dashboard with NextJS

https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication

I have added an auth system.
auth.config.ts
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
 
export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard');
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false;
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import type { User } from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

async function getUser(email: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
  try {
    const user = await sql<User>`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=${email}`;
    return user.rows[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch user:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch user.');
  }
}
 
export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const parsedCredentials = z
          .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6) })
          .safeParse(credentials);
 
        if (parsedCredentials.success) {
          const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
          const user = await getUser(email);
          if (!user) return null;

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
          if (passwordsMatch){
            return user;
          }
        }
 
        console.log('Invalid credentials');
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
});

middleware.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
 
export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;
 
export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};

Fetching the authorized user within dashboard/page.tsx
  const user = await auth();
  console.log(user);

I have this result
{
  user: { name: 'User toto', email: 'user@nextmail.com' },
  expires: '2025-01-12T13:47:17.724Z'
}

During the login, I return a User type from @/app/lib/definitions but in my page I got a User type from auth-core and my id is empty
name and email are filled correctly but not the identifier, how can I get the id of the logged user ?
I have created a session(session_id, user_id) table in my database, I save the client side session_id inside the cookie and in turn know which user is logged in, but is there an easier approach to directly get the id as name and email?
Thanks

Have you thought about storing the id in the users table under a column e.g user_id ? then you'd automatically retrieve the values as you're selecting all the columns from your Postgres user  table.
Just a thought, let me know.

It didn't work because auth() return a user who is type of User from @/app/lib/definitions who contains only name, email and image, that's not my own User type returned from my query

Quoting NextAuth callback docs:
"When using NextAuth.js with a database, the User object will be either a user object from the database (including the User ID) if the user has signed in before or a simpler prototype user object (i.e. name, email, image) for users who have not signed in before.
When using NextAuth.js without a database, the user object will always be a prototype user object, with information extracted from the profile"
Use the JWT callback to persist the user id right after a signin.
Cheers

You can store the user id in the session by using the session function below
auth/[...nextauth]
export { GET, POST } from "@/app/_lib/auth";

auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { createGuest, getGuest } from "./data-service";

const authConfig = {
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request }) {
      return !!auth?.user;
    },
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      try {
        const existingGuest = await getGuest(user.email);

        if (!existingGuest)
          await createGuest({ email: user.email, fullName: user.name });

        return true;
      } catch {
        return false;
      }
    },
    async session({ session, user }) {
      const guest = await getGuest(session.user.email);
      session.user.guestId = guest.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
};

export const {
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
  handlers: { GET, POST },
} = NextAuth(authConfig);

actions.ts

export async function deleteBooking(bookingId) {
  const session = await auth();
  if (!session) throw new Error("You must be logged in");

  const guestBookings = await getBookings(session.user.guestId);
  const guestBookingIds = guestBookings.map((booking) => booking.id);

  if (!guestBookingIds.includes(bookingId))
    throw new Error("You are not allowed to delete this booking");

  const { error } = await supabase
    .from("bookings")
    .delete()
    .eq("id", bookingId);

  if (error) throw new Error("Booking could not be deleted");

  revalidatePath("/account/reservations");
}

